# How can you contact a moderator who deleted a post

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

A moderator deleted an answer as I gave the same answer to two questions and the moderator would rather see one of the questions flagged as a duplicate.

I think the questions are a little different but I understand the point so deleted the second answer.

How do I get the first answer undeleted as this is the best place to put the answer - the comments are disabled and there does not seem to be anyway to communicate with the user.

As a side note - it would be much more user friendly if the moderator added a comment first before deleting, especially as the deletion happened shortly after I posted so we were both online.

Comment: Flag the post using moderator intervention with your concerns or ask in meta of site where your post was deleted.

Comment: @rene - thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Typically moderators or community members leave a comment when they vote to delete an answer verify that hasn't happened. You can see your own deleted answers